# Google Map Simple Polyline map to image

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polyline

I have to generate multiple google maps with polylines. May be 25 maps per page.
I can generate the maps with the coordinates. But for the page performance, can I generate these simple Polyline maps as Images? Can I get a Image instead of rendered google Map?
Thank You All!!!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to convert the map div to images.

It was working this way:

```
$('#map').html2canvas({
onrendered: function( canvas ) {
  var img = canvas.toDataURL()
  window.open(img);
}
```